# While compiling Snowflake UDF getting error SQL Error [1003] [42000]: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 7 at position 31 unexpected '{'

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I want the table names in a string variable Object_List as below
Object_List=('Table1,Table2,Table3)
and want the output as a Table of Values
RowNo  TableName
1      Table1
2      Table2
3      Table3.

The code giving error is as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Extract_TableNames(Object_List Varchar)

RETURNS TABLE ("TABLE_NAME" VARCHAR)

LANGUAGE SQL

AS

'

WITH DATATABLE(VALUEA) AS ( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM VALUES (Object_List) )

SELECT 
REPLACE(REPLACE(VALUE,'{',''),'}','')
SPLITTED_VALUE 
FROM DATATABLE , 
LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE (VALUEA,',') ;
    
'

;
```

Comment: Try changing the code block delimiters from a single quote to $$

Comment: I have tried the below code changed function from sql to javascript the compile error has gone but while calling the function as below SELECT * FROM TABLE(Extract_Tables('TABLE1,TABLE2,TABLE3,TABLE4'))  getting the following error: SQL Error [100131] [P0000]: JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in EXTRACT_TABLES at 'WITH DATATABLE(VALUEA) AS ( SELECT * FROM VALUES ( Object_List ) ) SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(VALUE,'{',''),'}','') SPLITTED_VALUE FROM DATATABLE , LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE (VALUEA,',') ;' position 5.

Comment: Please update your question with any additional information so everything is in one place - don't use comments except for comments

Comment: I tried $$ still I get the same error as above.

Comment: Does the complete SQL block run on its own i.e. outside of the function?

Answer (score 1):

Your embedded SQL in the function should not have a `;` in it.

Also you SQL can be simplified down to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Extract_TableNames(Object_List TEXT)
    RETURNS TABLE (TABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
AS $$
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(s.value,'{',''),'}','') AS splitted_value 
    FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE (object_list,',')) s
$$;
```

which can be used as:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(Extract_TableNames('{aa},{bb}'));
```

which gives:

| TABLE_NAME |
| --- |
| aa |
| bb |

showing the SQL working by itself outside of the function:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(s.value,'{',''),'}','') AS splitted_value 
    FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE ('{aa},{bb}',',')) s;
```

| TABLE_NAME |
| --- |
| aa |
| bb |

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked.

Comment: @NirmalKumarKosuru https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer